# Write nested lists column wise to CSV

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I have some list like so:

```
[['CD', 'CC', 'CD'], 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[['DT', 'CC', 'CD'], 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1] 
[['EX', 'CC', 'CD'], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] 
[['JJ', 'CC', 'CD'], 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]
```

And I want write these list into a csv file column wise. What I did so far:

```
for i in range(1,840):
    # function which compute the result value
    result=Count_SP(i,leng_second,first_position+1,second_position)
    final.append(result)


print final             # final contains lists      
File_Write(final)       # File_Write() writes the final into a csv file
```

Output needed:

```
['CD', 'CC', 'CD'],['DT', 'CC', 'CD'],['EX', 'CC', 'CD'],['JJ', 'CC', 'CD']
1,0,0,0
1,0,0,0
1,1,0,1
1,0,0,0
1,1,0,1
1,0,0,0
1,1,0,1
1,1,0,1
1,1,0,0
1,1,0,1
1,1,0,1
1,1,0,1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put your lists in a container then it's actually quite simple:

```
import csv

container = [[['CD', 'CC', 'CD'], 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
             [['DT', 'CC', 'CD'], 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
             [['EX', 'CC', 'CD'], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
             [['JJ', 'CC', 'CD'], 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]]

with open('out.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    csvw = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for column in zip(*[s for s in container]):
        csvw.writerow(column)
```

This create the file `out.csv` which will contain the input lists column wise:

```
"['CD', 'CC', 'CD']","['DT', 'CC', 'CD']","['EX', 'CC', 'CD']","['JJ', 'CC', 'CD']"
1,0,0,0
1,0,0,0
1,1,0,1
1,0,0,0
1,1,0,1
1,0,0,0
1,1,0,1
1,1,0,1
1,1,0,0
1,1,0,1
1,1,0,1
1,1,0,1
```